# Convert System.Drawing.Font.Size to WPF FontSize

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms, fonts, font-size

I need to convert a GDI Font in a WPF "Font".

```
myGdiFont As System.Drawing.Font
```

in

```
_Family As Windows.Media.FontFamily
_Style As Windows.FontStyle
_Weight As Windows.FontWeight
_Size As Double
```

In particularry, I need to Convert

```
_Size = myGdiFont.Size (???)
```

The size in WinForms font is in Units or Points... In WPF is in Pixels... How to convert from one to another?

**PS.**
Follwing the Clemens indications, is it correct?

```
  Dim myDrawingFont As New System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 10)
  Dim myWpfLabel As New Windows.Controls.Label
  myWpfLabel.FontSize = myDrawingFont.SizeInPoints * 72 / 96
```

Fixed:

```
  myWpfLabel.FontSize = myDrawingFont.SizeInPoints * 96 / 72
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By multiplication. A point is 1/72th of an inch, whereas WPF device-independent units ("WPF pixels") are 1/96th of an inch.

You can verify this by specifying a WPF control's [FontSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.fontsize.aspx) property in XAML as for example "24" and "18pt". You will realize that both values result in the same actual font size.

Comment: No, it should be `myWpfLabel.FontSize = myDrawingFont.SizeInPoints / 72 * 96`.