# Convert the Font size in inch

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, vb.net, gdi+

I need to convert between `Drawing.Font.Size` (float, ?) and WPF `FontSize` (double, WPF pixels).

Finally, I decided to store in the database the fontSize in inch...

How can I convert the GDI FontSize to inch and the WPF FontSize to inch?

```
sizeInInch = wpfFontSize / 96
sizeInInch = gdiFontSize / ?
```

Can I use something DPI independent? Maybe `System.Windows.FontSizeConverter`?

I need to convert to something, that will allow me to switch multiple time between WPF and GDI without changing the "real value".

Each division and following multiplication will accumulate errors...

FontSizeConverter does a ConvertTo, but I don't understand to use it:
say

```
myUniversalFontSize = (double)(myFontSizeConverter.ConvertFrom(
    gdiFont.SizeInPoints.ToString() + "pt"))
```

will transform my gdiFont size in ...? WPF Pixels?

How now should I convert back that value to GDI?

```
gdiFont.SizeInPoints = myUniversalFontSize / 96 * 72???
```

Can I use in the second example the `myFontSizeConverter` too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.control.fontsize.aspx

```
"in is inches; 1in==96px"
```

Use a LengthConverter for conversion. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.lengthconverter.aspx

Comment: I need for both. 96 is for WPF, but for GDI?

Comment: I don't understand the LenghtConverter... I need to convert to something, that will allow me to switch multiple time between WPF and GDI without changing the "real value". Each division and following multiplication will accumulate errors...

Comment: You might be able to store in DB as 1 for 1 in.  You would use the LengthConverter to assign size to the fonts and they would be rendered properly.  But now I am guessing.  As I understand your question more I don't really have an answer at this time.  Sorry

Answer (score 0):

Don't know much about the WPF stuff, but if there is a method to convert from pixels to points, you can use the scale of 1 inch = 72 points.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9700753/convert-system-drawing-font-size-to-wpf-fontsize

Comment: Agree I thought 1 in = 72 points but in MS documentation it is 96

Comment: I don't see that. I see them showing that a point is relative to pixels per inch divided by 72. A point is 1/72 inch. If you have 96 pixels per inch then 1 point = 1.333333 pixels.