# C# DrawString() resolution

Tags: c#, string, gdi

I am drawing a string on a PictureBox using `DrawString()` inside `OnPaint()`. It looks like this:

[image]

Now when I draw the exact same string on a `Graphics` object obtained from `Graphics.FromImage()` the string is much smaller and unreadable. The image I draw on is `5184 x 3456` and the font is declared as follows:

`new Font("Arial", 16.0f, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.World);`

I tried all `GraphicsUnit`s, but it makes absolutely no difference. How do I draw the font independent from image resolution?

**Edit:**

I fail to see how the "draw code" is relevant in this case, but here you go:

```
void DrawOverlay(Graphics g, Font fnt, int containerWidth, int containerHeight)
        {
            if (!OverlayCheck.Checked)
                return;

            float padding = 5.0f;
            float offset = 5.0f;

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.AppendFormat("{0}\n", ISOComboBox.Text);
            sb.AppendFormat("Exp. Time: {0}\n", TVComboBox.Text);
            sb.AppendFormat("Aperture: {0}\n", AVComboBox.Text);

            using (var tb = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(150, 0,0,0)))
            {
                string infoStr = sb.ToString();
                SizeF infoStrSize = g.MeasureString(infoStr, fnt);
                var infoStrDim = new SizeF(infoStrSize.Width + padding * 2, infoStrSize.Height + padding * 2);

                g.FillRectangle(tb, offset, containerHeight - offset - infoStrDim.Height, infoStrDim.Width, infoStrDim.Height);
                g.DrawString(infoStr, fnt, Brushes.White, offset + padding, containerHeight - infoStrDim.Height);

                if (TitleTextBox.Text.Length > 0)
                {
                    var titleStr = SpliceText(TitleTextBox.Text, 15);
                    SizeF titleStrSize = g.MeasureString(titleStr, fnt);
                    var titleStrDim = new SizeF(titleStrSize.Width + padding * 2, titleStrSize.Height + padding * 2);

                    g.FillRectangle(tb, offset, offset, titleStrDim.Width, titleStrDim.Height);
                    g.DrawString(titleStr, fnt, Brushes.White, offset + padding, offset + padding);
                }
            }
        }
```

Some background: The image drawn on the PictureBox is a low-res, live stream from a camera. `DrawOverlay()` is called inside OnPaint() to render the text overlay.

When the camera captures a picture it has has higher resolution (5184 x 3456). I create a graphics context from that image (`Graphics.FromImage()`) and 
`DrawOverlay()` again. This time the text is way smaller, which makes sense due to higher resolution. I want the text to have equal size in both images.

The live view has 96/96 dpi (DpiX, DpiY), while the high-res image has 72/72. So I need to scale the font relative to dpi.

Comment: You could try using [`TextRenderer.DrawText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.drawtext(v=vs.110).aspx), it has a bunch more options and actually draws nicer looking text than `Graphics.DrawString`.  I'm not sure if it can handle this exact situation directly or not though.  Worst case, use `MeasureString` in a loop that slowly increases the font size until you find the size one step below it gets too big to fit in a rectangle scaled to the image resolution.

Comment: Any fixed size would look relatively different when applied to 300x200 picture and 5000x3000 picture... You need to figure out what exactly you expect when you say "independent from image resolution" and just apply math you've come up with... Maybe you want font size to be fixed percentage of the whole image?

Comment: Such a large image needs to be shrunk by PictureBox to fit it in the control.  That of course now makes the text smaller as well.

Comment: @HansPassant I am drawing a low-res version of the 5184 x 3456 image *on* the PictureBox. I am not using it's image property. It should not be scaled.

Comment: Then show us your draw code that reproduces it.

Comment: Hi, I am not sure what you want to achieve or if it is possible. The size of the image is the least of your worries, DPI is more important.

In order to better control the size of the printed text (even though it will never be perfect), you need to take DPI into account. Depending on what you are doing, something like:

    inches = pixels / dpi,
    pixels = inches * dpi

For the size of the font. Also, be careful that you will deal with 2 dpi's, the image's dpi and the monitor's dpi. Have fun with the formulas!

Comment: You can check here for a reference discussion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9840810/convert-the-font-size-in-inch

Comment: @LarsTech I've updated my post.

Comment: cute elephant..

Comment: @pm100 We don't talk about the elephant in the room.